# broken css background image links show in Safari/Chrome, nothing in Firefox

Tags: css, image, background-image, broken-links

If you view [this page](http://kimberlygenevieve.com/portraits/?show=slide) in Safari and Chrome you'll find two broken images links below the image; if viewed in Firefox you'll find nothing. Why is this? How do I get the images to appear?

```
.navigation { 
    padding: 20px 20px 0 0;
}

.navigation .arrowLeft a,
.navigation .prev { 
    float: left;
    background: url(img/arrow-left.png) no-repeat left center;
}

.navigation .arrowRight a,
.navigation .next { 
    float: right;
    background: url(img/arrow-right.png) no-repeat right center;
}

.ngg-galleryoverview {
    min-height: 600px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like you have the wrong links for the images, but if you want firefox to display broken images then you could try [This](http://gavtaylor.co.uk/blog/enable-broken-image-placeholders-in-firefox)

Comment: The image links should be correct. They are [here](http://kimberlygenevieve.com/wp-content/themes/frsh%20theme/img/arrow-left.png) and [here](http://kimberlygenevieve.com/wp-content/themes/frsh%20theme/img/arrow-right.png)

Comment: Oh, I see. These navigation pictures are not in the ones you think they are in.

they are in the "nav" div not the "navigation" div

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I have no images assigned to `nav`.